# Static code analyzer for .NET for OWASP vulnerabilities

Tags: c#, .net, security, owasp

I am looking for a static code analyzer which can detect [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) vulnerabilities.

- SonarAnalyzer which is an in-built repository in SonarQube covers
  only few of the OWASP Top 10.
- [Roslyn security guard](https://dotnet-security-guard.github.io/rules.htm) for .NET is
  also focused on security but I do not see any information on how many
  of the OWASP vulnerabilities are covered.

Are there any other open source/commercial static checkers available which provide comprehensive coverage of  all of the OWASP Top 10 for C#?

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather open-ended, however if you are strictly looking for a Static Application Security Testing (SAST) tool (without knowing your budget), you may want to look into [Checkmarx](https://www.checkmarx.com/).

There are some open-source solutions, such as [Bandit](https://github.com/openstack/bandit) for Python however like most SAST tools, they have such a high false positive rate that I end up tweaking the threshold heavily for stuff like Continuous Integration (CI & CD).

Other than that, there are also Dynamic Application Security Testing (DAST) tools which tend to be language and framework agnostic and are more behavioral (which I prefer) such as [Acunetix](https://www.acunetix.com). The downside is that scans can take longer to run when compared to their counterparts.